# Using redirect in my htaccess to pass variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?search=qualified
```

I need it to redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/scrabble-dictionary/word/qualified
```

I tried

```
Redirect 301 /search.php?search=qualified http://www.example.com/scrabble-dictionary/word/
```

In my htaccess file but that produced the url

```
http://www.example.com/scrabble-dictionary/word/?search=qualified
```

How can I get a rewrite to redirect to the url I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite instead to get finer control.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?search=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /scrabble-dictionary/word/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: works perfect, Im assuming changing 302 to 301 will invoke the "Permanent Redirect"